# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: gherkin/util/FixJava while running cucumber test using JUnit

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

I'm trying to run a cucumber test with `JUnit` and getting exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/util/FixJava
```

RunnerClass:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 


    @RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
    @Cucumber.Options(
            features = ".//FeatureFile", //the path of the feature files
            glue= "StepDfb"
            )


    public class RunTest { 

    }
```

Exception stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/util/FixJava
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<clinit>(RuntimeOptions.java:25)
    at cucumber.junit.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:30)
    at cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.util.FixJava
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

I have added the below Cucumber **jar files** to Eclipse and added the cucumber plugin to eclipse

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Any help to fix this issue is much appreciated

Comment: You don't have the right dependencies. Either a wrong version or missing all together. Don't manually manage your dependencies. Remove transitive dependencies from your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using different versions for your Cucumber dependencies. Make sure to use the same version for all your Cucumber dependencies to prevent problems.
2. You are explicitly importing dependencies that are transitive dependencies. Remove these from your pom.xml.
3. You are using a *very* old version of Cucumber. Please use a more recent one.

You can find the dependencies you need and their most recent version in the cucumber docs: cucumber.io/docs under installation: https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/

Answer (score -2):

The way is you download gherkin-2.12.2.jar, gherkin-2.12.2-sources.jar 
files from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/cukes/gherkin/2.12.2/ and add them in your library.

Comment: Please, provide some more information, otherwise, purpose of these actions look magical to say the least.

Comment: Agree with @eagle.dan.1349 . Welcome to StackOverflow :) please refer  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)